# NPE on onTouchEvent in MMAdView

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, touch-event

I have followed all the steps described [here](http://wiki.millennialmedia.com/index.php/Android)

add doesn't appear but when i touch the add area it gives me NPE

```
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView.onTouchEvent(MMAdView.java:631)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-10 15:37:20.564: E/AndroidRuntime(715):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

calling my add from onCreate

```
Hashtable<String, String> map = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        map.put("age", "45");
        map.put("zip", "90210");
        map.put("income", "50000");
        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutadd);
        adview = new MMAdView(Result.this, MYAPID, MMAdView.BANNER_AD_BOTTOM, 30,map);//(Result.this, MYAPID,"MMBannerAdBottom", 30,false);
         adview.setId(MMAdViewSDK.DEFAULT_VIEWID + 1);
         myLayout.addView(adview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
         MMAdListener listener = new MyAdListener();
          adview.setListener(new com.millennialmedia.android.BasicMMAdListener());//listener);
          adview.callForAd();
```

Note: this thing happens with latest millennial media only. older version says no add return in logcat and continues to work.

**EDIT:** after lots of things i moved to xml and it was working like champ. now i think problem with java code is adview was not added to view properly and hence touching the space of ad was giving the NPE. Can any one tell more about this?

Comment: line no 631 of MMAdView.java ?

Comment: @SamirMangroliya yes exactly.Do you have any idea?

Comment: can anybody tell whats the matter with above code

Comment: Without knowing the code at line 631 of the MMAdView we can't help. You should contact the support of that library.

Comment: @WarrenFaith now how can i give you code at line no 631 of MMAdView.java? its Millennial media's file.

Comment: @WarrenFaith if others are using it then there must be some way to achieve this.

Comment: Ask their support. As I said before. Please read the complete comment next time.